# Added SIP-headers in MSPL application missing/being removed in Lync 2013

Tags: sip, lync, lync-server-2013

I've got a managed SIP application / server application in Lync 2013, and try to add a header (History-Info and a proprietary one), and I can see it added in the e.Request.AllHeaders collection. But when the request is passed on and i see it in OCSLogger, the header is not there in the SIP-request.

Is there any mechanism in Lync 2013 that will block or remove new headers, or some other reason why this might happen?

Comment: It seems the Mediation Server will strip away any headers it does not like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the Mediation Server will strip away any headers it does not like. If a call comes in from a SIP trunk on the other hand, it will allow the History-Info header and a few others to be added and manipulated.

And, there does not seem to exist any way of changing this Mediation Server behavior.